# Why does knockout only bind my table the first time?

Tags: web-applications, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following code that binds an HTML table to a list of Person object using knockout:

```
function PersonModel(person) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = person.Id;
    self.firstName = person.FirstName;
    self.surname = person.Surname;
    self.email = person.Email;
    self.cell = person.Cell;
}

function PersonListModel(personList) {
    var self = this;
    self.persons = ko.observableArray(personList);
}

function getPersonList() {
    $.getJSON("Person/IndexJson", function (allData) {
        var mappedPersons = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new PersonModel(item); });
        ko.applyBindings(new PersonListModel(mappedPersons), $("#person-list")[0]);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        getPersonList();
    });
    getPersonList();            
});
```

The HTML being bound looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="person-list" data-bind="foreach: persons">
        <tr data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': id }, click: $parent.personClicked">
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: surname"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: email"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: cell"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="refresh" href="#"></a>
```

My problem is that the table is only properly populated the first time the page loads. On all subsequent ajax calls, triggered by clicking the Refresh link, the table is empty. The same ajax result is returned in all cases, so I suspect I may be missing some knockout call that 'frees up' the initial binding to make way for subsequent bindings or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do the new modeling inside your ajax routine.  Below should solve your problem

```
var perList = ko.observableArray({});

function getPersonList() {
    $.getJSON("Person/IndexJson", function(allData) {
        var mappedPersons = $.map(allData, function(item) {
            return new PersonModel(item);
        });
        perList(PersonListModel(mappedPersons));
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(perList, $("#person-list")[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. Although I'm sure it will apply elsewhere,  it does not answer my question and does nothing to address my problem. As I say in the question, the table **is binding correctly** the first time.

Comment: Its been my experience that rebinding to new ko.observable is the primary reason why bindings only work the first time.